# Why does sin of the same number return two very different values?

Tags: c++, casting, trigonometry

Can someone explain why these two outputs are vastly different?

When I print out `(float)direction*PI/180.0f` and `theta` they both evaluate to 1.5708 as expected.  Why does putting one in a float variable before putting it in the `sin` function make such a huge difference in output?  Also note that `test2` returns the correct answer (1), while `test` returns the wrong answer (0).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#define PI 3.14159265


int main()
{   
    int direction = 90;
    float theta = (float)direction*PI/180.0f;
    int test =  (int)sin(theta);
    int test2 = (int)sin((float)direction*PI/180.0f);
    
    std::cout << theta << " " << (float)direction*PI/180.0f << " " << test << " " << test2;
}
```

Comment: Because `direction/180` in the initialization of `test2` is still performing integer division. You might want to try `180.0f` to perform division with `float` instead

Comment: Thanks for replying! I just edited to change to 180.0f and am still having the same issue.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve casting the return value of `sin` to an int? This discards the fractional part, effectively rounding towards zero. Perhaps you want [`std::round`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) instead?

Comment: hoping to achieve a better understanding of c++ my friend.  This problem came up when I was using the sin function in a larger equation which would eventually be rounded to an integer value.

Comment: Your problem is that you are not understanding that `sin()` is guaranteed to produce a result between `-1` and `1`, so  converting it to `int` always produces `0` except in the case where `sin()` returns exactly `-1.0` (which is rare).

Comment: my goodness, thank you Peter I am a fool.  I had it stuck in my head that (int) cast would round to the nearest integer, but it always floors it.  Thank you!!

Comment: A lot of people are floored by that revelation.

Comment: `the correct answer (1)` No, the correct answer is not `1`. Mathematically it is `sin(3.14159265/2) =`  [`0.999999999999999998389173...`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%2890+*+3.14159265+%2F+180%29&assumption=%22TrigRD%22+-%3E+%22R%22), because `#define PI 3.14159265` is a rather poor approximation of `π`. It then gets compounded by the limited precision of floating point calculations, but this shows that even the basic premise of the question is wrong.

Comment: Closely related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @dxiv The correct answer (for IEEE floating point) is `1`, since the closest `double`/`float` to that exact value is `1`.

Comment: @HTNW That is true, but not so relevant to OP's question. It is true as a consequence of the lucky chance that `sin` is almost flat around `π/2`. But, in general, one should not feed approximations with 9 significant digits into a calculation and expect results with 17 exact significant digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rounding errors.
Your test variable is < 1.0, your test2 variable is >= 1.0.
I C and C++, 0.9999999999999 gets rounded to 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#define PI 3.14159265


int main()
{   
    int direction = 90;
    float theta = (float)direction*PI/180.0f;
    auto test =  sin(theta);
    auto test2 = sin((float)direction*PI/180.0f);
    
    std::cout << theta << " " << (float)direction*PI/180.0f << " " << (int) test << " " << (int) test2 << std::endl;
    std::cout <<std::boolalpha << "test >= 1.0 = " << (test >= 1.0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "test2 >= 1.0 = " << (test2 >= 1.0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "test == test2 = " << (test == test2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "test < test2 = " << (test < test2) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1.5708 1.5708 0 1
test >= 1.0 = false
test2 >= 1.0 = true
test == test2 = false
test < test2 = true
```

Answer (score 3):

`(float)direction*PI/180.0f` uses *`double`* arithmetic. `PI` is a `double` literal, since it has no `f` suffix. The other two operands (`(float)direction` and `180.0f`) are `float`s, yes, but they just get promoted to `double` (and the conversion is exact in IEEE floating point). Note that the `(float)` is only applying to `direction` due to operator precedence. For `test2`, you pass the resulting `double` directly to `sin`, and `sin` returns exactly `1`. For `test`, you cast the `double` down to `float` in the assignment to `theta` first, and then you cast it back up to `double` for the call to `sin` (note that you are calling C's `double sin(double)`, not C++'s `float std::sin(float)`). Through the casts, `theta` loses a little of its value to rounding. `sin` then gives a value correspondingly a little less than `1`, which then rounds all the way to `0` when cast to `int`. If you had called `std::sin`, then you would have gotten `1`, since `std::sin` would round that slightly less than `1` `double` into a `float`, which would give `1` (unlike truncating to `int`).

Printing floating point values to `std::cout` like this is not useful for debugging floating point, since the values get rounded. I like using `std::hexfloat`, which shows the *real* binary values (converted to hexadecimal), not decimal lies. I've also gotten rid of `PI` and turned the C-style casts into functional-style casts to show what's going on more clearly. I've turned `test` and `test2` into `double`s (`sin`'s return type) so we can take a real look at them.

```
int main() {
    int direction = 90;
    float theta = float(direction)*3.14159265/180.0f;
    double test1 = sin(theta);
    double test2 = sin(float(direction)*3.14159265/180.0f);
    std::cout << std::hexfloat;
    std::cout << theta << " " << float(direction)*3.14159265/180.0f << "\n";
    std::cout << test1 << " " << test2 << "\n";
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:11,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:11,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:4),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccmath%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++int+direction+%3D+90%3B%0A++++float+theta+%3D+float(direction)*3.14159265/180.0f%3B%0A++++int+test1+%3D+sin(theta)%3B%0A++++int+test2+%3D+sin(float(direction)*3.14159265/180.0f)%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+std::hexfloat%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+theta+%3C%3C+%22+%22+%3C%3C+float(direction)*3.14159265/180.0f+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:61.57237325495959,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1100,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+11.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27),(h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:clang1100,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+11.0.0+Executor+(Editor+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:38.42762674504041,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:1,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

It gives

```
0x1.921fb6p+0 0x1.921fb53c8d4fp+0
0x1.ffffffffffff7p-1 0x1p+0
```

Which neatly shows us that the value we're using in `test2` has more digits than `theta`, since it's a `double` but `float theta`. You also see that `test1` is almost `1`, but not quite.